# How do I fix/edit this regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

> lcl|NZ_AP012542.1_cds_WP_003600377.1_1 [locus_tag=LBPC_RS14705] [db_xref=GeneID:31583580] [protein=RepB family plasmid replication initiator protein] [protein_id=WP_003600377.1] [location=1..780] [gbkey=CDS]
>   ATGGCAAATACAATCAACAAAAAACAAAATCTGGCGATGCAGGCGTTGCTTAAACGCCAAGACTATCTTG
>
> lcl|NZ_AP012542.1_cds_WP_016377574.1_2 [locus_tag=LBPC_RS14710] [db_xref=GeneID:31583581] [protein=DUF536 domain-containing protein] [protein_id=WP_016377574.1] [location=complement(1459..1956)] [gbkey=CDS]
>   ATGAGTAAGACCATCAAAGAACTTGCAGAGGAATTGAGCTTATCTAAATCTGGTATTCGTAAATATCTAA

I want to extract word after locus_tag= (only LBPC_RS14705 and LBPC_RS14710). How do I fix this regular expression?

[locus_tag][=]\w+

Comment: What exactly do you want as your desired output, `LBPC_RS14705` or the whole text after it?

Comment: @rv7 Just only LBPC_RS14705 and LBPC_RS14710.

Comment: You need a capturing group around your `\w+`, [like this](https://regex101.com/r/HaDJsQ/1)

Comment: @rv7 Thanks a lot! It's very helpful for me.

Comment: @Glufflix I updated my answer to retrieve both tags

Comment: @Nick Parsons thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regular expression to match the `locus_tag`:

`/\[locus_tag=(\w+)]/g;`

In this expression, I have captured word characters after the "locus_tag=" and so you can access it by doing `.exec(str)[1]` twice to get both of the tags.

See a working example below:

```js
const str = 
`lcl|NZ_AP012542.1_cds_WP_003600377.1_1 [locus_tag=LBPC_RS1477705] [db_xref=GeneID:31583580] [protein=RepB family plasmid replication initiator protein] [protein_id=WP_003600377.1] [location=1..780] [gbkey=CDS] ATGGCAAATACAATCAACAAAAAACAAAATCTGGCGATGCAGGCGTTGCTTAAACGCCAAGACTATCTTG

lcl|NZ_AP012542.1_cds_WP_016377574.1_2 [locus_tag=LBPC_RS14710] [db_xref=GeneID:31583581] [protein=DUF536 domain-containing protein] [protein_id=WP_016377574.1] [location=complement(1459..1956)] [gbkey=CDS] ATGAGTAAGACCATCAAAGAACTTGCAGAGGAATTGAGCTTATCTAAATCTGGTATTCGTAAATATCTAA`;

const regex = /\[locus_tag=(\w+)]/g;
console.log(regex.exec(str)[1]); // Run exec once to get the first match
console.log(regex.exec(str)[1]); // Run exec twice to get the second match
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try any of the following approaches.

> Here I've assumed your locus tag has word characters as I can see. And `\w+` is there to match it.
>
> Helpful link: https://javascript.info/regexp-groups

#### 1st way

```
var s1 = "lcl|NZ_AP012542.1_cds_WP_003600377.1_1 [locus_tag=LBPC_RS14705] [db_xref=GeneID:31583580] [protein=RepB family plasmid replication initiator protein] [protein_id=WP_003600377.1] [location=1..780] [gbkey=CDS] ATGGCAAATACAATCAACAAAAAACAAAATCTGGCGATGCAGGCGTTGCTTAAACGCCAAGACTATCTTG";

var s2 = "lcl|NZ_AP012542.1_cds_WP_016377574.1_2 [locus_tag=LBPC_RS14710] [db_xref=GeneID:31583581] [protein=DUF536 domain-containing protein] [protein_id=WP_016377574.1] [location=complement(1459..1956)] [gbkey=CDS] ATGAGTAAGACCATCAAAGAACTTGCAGAGGAATTGAGCTTATCTAAATCTGGTATTCGTAAATATCTAA";

const regEx = /(locus_tag=(\w+))/;

var locus_tag1 = s1.match(regEx)[2];
var locus_tag2 = s2.match(regEx)[2];

console.log(locus_tag1); // LBPC_RS14705
console.log(locus_tag2); // LBPC_RS14710
```

#### 2nd way

```
var s1 = "lcl|NZ_AP012542.1_cds_WP_003600377.1_1 [locus_tag=LBPC_RS14705] [db_xref=GeneID:31583580] [protein=RepB family plasmid replication initiator protein] [protein_id=WP_003600377.1] [location=1..780] [gbkey=CDS] ATGGCAAATACAATCAACAAAAAACAAAATCTGGCGATGCAGGCGTTGCTTAAACGCCAAGACTATCTTG";

var s2 = "lcl|NZ_AP012542.1_cds_WP_016377574.1_2 [locus_tag=LBPC_RS14710] [db_xref=GeneID:31583581] [protein=DUF536 domain-containing protein] [protein_id=WP_016377574.1] [location=complement(1459..1956)] [gbkey=CDS] ATGAGTAAGACCATCAAAGAACTTGCAGAGGAATTGAGCTTATCTAAATCTGGTATTCGTAAATATCTAA";

const regEx = /(locus_tag=\w+)/;

var locus_tag1 = s1.match(regEx)[0].split('=')[1];
var locus_tag2 = s2.match(regEx)[0].split('=')[1];

console.log(locus_tag1); // LBPC_RS14705
console.log(locus_tag2); // LBPC_RS14710
```